# pgAdmin 4 Crashes on Query Builder (before executing query)

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am dealing with a frustrating issue (pgAdmin crashes on query builder) that is described in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10572/postgres-pgadmin-iii-query-builder-crash?newreg=105c812e4aaa49cd96ed6c209e71faf4) dealing with pgAdmin 3. The accepted answer gives the solution of deleting a file that was corrupted, but I can't find the file on Mac. I suspect that it is named differently in pgAdmin4.

Where can I find “pgadmin_histoqueries.xml” (mentioned in the linked question) equivalent for pgAdmin 4 on Mac?

Comment: Can you provide logs from pgAdmin4.log file? https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#8

Answer (score 1):

In mac home directory you can find `.pgadmin` hidden file. Use `ls -la` in terminal to show all hidden files in the current directory. You can delete or 
rename with `mv .pgadmin .pgadmin.bak`. Then restart to make sure. 
Hope it will help you.